# Adding a TestCase to a SubSuite (ITestSuiteBase)

Tags: c#, tfs

I am attempting to add a Test Case to a test suite.

The layout in MTM is like the following:

```
-Top TestCase
    - Test Feature
       - New TestCase
```

So I'd like to add the `New TestCase`.

I have `SubSuits` which is listing `Test Feature` and is `ITestSuiteBase` but I am unable to add anything to it. An exception is getting thrown with the message of : `Cannot add, remove or change items`.

```
public void CopyTestCaseIntoTestSuite(ITestCase sourceTestCase)
{
    // SelectedSubSuite is typeof ITestSuiteBase
    SelectedSubSuit.TestCases.Add(sourceTestCase); // Fails here
}
```

Anyone else been able to add to a `ITestSuiteBase`?

Comment: Did you add the Feature as a requirement based type? If so you need a Static Suit in order to add manually!

Comment: Sorry. I'm quite new to the TFS Api, do you have any examples?

Comment: Did you create a Static or Requitement based Suit? You can't use TestCases.Add on a requirement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ITestSuiteBase.TestCases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.itestsuitebase.testcases.aspx) property is read-only, so it is not allowed to add one test case with code: SelectedSubSuit.TestCases.Add(sourceTestCase);

You need to use the following code instead:

```
IStaticTestSuite staticTestSuite = SelectedSubSuit as IStaticTestSuite;
staticTestSuite.Entries.Add(sourceTestCase);
this.Plan.Save();
```

Comment: What is the type of `Plan`?

Comment: @JamieRees, the type is ITestPlan: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.itestplan.aspx